# How to pass value to PHP Script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have code in my html file as below. I am using jQuery Mobile

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://localhost/owner_pickup.php",
     cache: false,
     dataType:'json'
     success: function(data)
      {
            // On success
      } 
});
```

`owner_pickup.php` returns me data by executing query. Now i need to pass a value which i would read in my `owner_pickup.php` file.
Kindly suggest me how would we pass the value

Comment: please be more specific about what your goals are. Values can be passed in both directions

Comment: Specify what data you want to pass? and by what name ? Question Is Not Clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "http://localhost/owner_pickup.php", 
    data: {param1: 123, param2: "text value"},
    cache: false, 
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) { // On success } 
});
```

Comment: I am not able to read it in my php page. can you help me how would i parse the passed values in my php page

Comment: e.g. `echo 'param1=' . $_GET['param1'];`

Answer (score 2):

in your php file:

```
$value = array(
  "dat_1" => "this is data number 1",
  "dat_2" => "this is data number 2"
);

echo json_encode($value);
```

in your jquery finction:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://localhost/owner_pickup.php",
     cache: false,
     dataType:'json'
     success: function(data)
      {
            var value1 = data.dat_1;
            var value2 = data.dat_2;
      } 
});
```

please look at this answers:
[retrieve multiple values from ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318044/retrieve-multiple-values-from-ajax-call/26318248#26318248)

if you don't know how to use JSON please google it.

edit:
pass a value to the php:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://localhost/owner_pickup.php",
     cache: false,
     data: {
            first_value:50,
            second_value:55
           }
     dataType:'json'
     success: function(data)
      {
            var value1 = data.dat_1;
            var value2 = data.dat_2;
      } 
});
```

in the php:

```
if(isset($_GET['first_value'])) 
  $first = $_GET['first_value'];
```

Comment: i need to pass value in ajax call. What you have shown is how to parse once call is success

Comment: there is no such thing as a `JSON object`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://localhost/owner_pickup.php",
     data:{key1:value1}
     cache: false,
     dataType:'json'
     success: function(data)
      {
      } 
});
```

In php aaccept it as

```
<?php
$_REQUEST['key1'];
?>
```